# Git in Visual Studio Code - Push to not working on context menu

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code

I have started using Git with Visual Studio Code.

1) When pushing it with the console `git push origin` it always works, i'm only get asked for the password and then the push works.

2) But when I trying it with the contextmenu in visual studio code it always brings me an error.

[image]

**When clicking on "Push to" I get following view. Here I choose "origin".**

[image]

> root@xxxx.de: Permission denied
>   (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.